# Uncertainty in Range of Projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, differentiation, error-analysis

If we are given that a projectile is launched with velocity 10m/s at an angle of $45^\circ$ and uncertainty in angle is of $0.5^\circ$ . What is the uncertainty in the range of projectile.
The problem I am facing here is that I am getting the uncertainty in range to be $0$ as by differentiating, and substituting $45^\circ$ , my $dR$ becomes 0.

Any explanations?

$R=\frac{u^2\sin2\theta}{g}$

$\frac{dR}{R}=\frac{2\cos2\theta}{\sin2\theta}d\theta$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: what part of this looks like homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the problem for an arbitrary angle first. Then plug in the "ideal" angle to get the "perfect shot" solution.  To evaluate the sensitivity of the solution, find the ranges for the $+/-$ cases individually, and report the results.

The method used in the OP can fail when used at a critical point, as the derivative is by definition 0 at this point, and the region nearby tends to be very flat when very close; the result is that obtain zero for your answer.

So in this case abandon elegance, and just evaluate!

Comment: but isnt the more elegant way to differentiate the equation  after taking ln on both sides?

Comment: You would have to try both ways and see (1) do you get the same answers, and (2) decided which method is more elegant.  If (1) is true then (2) is a matter of taste.  But your question begins with (1) not working for you, so my suggestion is to work on obtaining a correct, general solution first.

Comment: But why isn't (1) working? Its not like the error in angle is too much to replace d(theta) to (del)(Theta). Also, (1) would work for any angle other than 45*

Comment: Show us the formula you are using for the range, and how you arrived at it.

Comment: Take log both sides and differentiate to get to the expression. Replace the differential quantity with the uncertainty. It should work as the uncertainty is very small compared to (theta)

Comment: @KrackJack: I've updated the answer with an analysis of why your method fails in this case.